# How to await FB.login() callback on reactjs?

Tags: facebook, reactjs

I want to use a async function that posts API with FB token after fb login.(like below) Unfortunately, undefined accessToken is output before login callback.

```
// fbsdk
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
export default async function request(url, options) {

    let accessToken =  await FB.login(function (res) {
      console.log(res.authResponse.accessToken)
      return res.authResponse.accessToken;
    });

    console.log(accessToken);
    url = url+ '/access_token?=' + accessToken
    const response = await fetch(url,  {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {'access_token': accessToken},
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    const ret = {
      data,
      headers: {},
    };

    if (response.headers.get('x-total-count')) {
      ret.headers['x-total-count'] = response.headers.get('x-total-count');
    }

    console.log(ret);

    return ret;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `window.FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', your_callback_function)` and in your_callback_function you can get accessToken from facebook.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)